# Make mouse pointer become hand to click button

Tags: asp.net, jquery

```
<td id="btnIcOld" style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Load.png")%>" />
</td>

$('#btnIcOld').live('click', function () {
    window.location.href = 'https://extranetint.chathamfinancial.com/indications/swapcalculator';
});
```

So as you can see above, the image is my button, and that is the JQuery that handles the button click. Problem is, when you hover your mouse over the image, it stays as the basic arrow pointer. How do I make it change to a hand so the user knows they can click on it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can edit your style for the column to be `cursor:pointer` see [CSS cursor property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

```
<td id="btnIcOld" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
    <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Load.png")%>" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cursor:pointer` in your CSS style. [See here for some CSS Cursors](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470321/CSS-and-Cursors.htm)

Alternatively, is there no way to wrap it in an `a` tag, pointing to the link you need?

Comment: `cursor:hand;` doesn't work in Mozilla and Chrome, `cursor:pointer;` does

Answer (score 1):

Change the cursor's style when above the image:

```
<td id="btnIcOld" style="text-align:center;">
    <img style="cursor: pointer" src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Load.png")%>" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is pretty much right, but I would recommend splitting those styles out for maintainability.  Try something like this:

main.css:

```
.txtCenter  { text-align:center; }
.clickImage { cursor:pointer; }
```

ASPX page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path\to\main.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        ...

        <td id="btnIcOld" class="txtCenter">
            <img class="clickImage" src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Load.png")%>" />
        </td>

        ...
    </body>
</html>
```